# AJAX success call back not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here is the code I am using to access my web API controller named `Owner`; the `success` function is not being called. Any ideas?

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'http://localhost:26533/api/Owner',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        success: function (response) {  alert("yes"); }                  
});
```

Comment: Why have you specified a contentType for a GET request? GET requests don't have content to describe the type of.

Comment: What does the JavaScript error console say? What does the Net tab say (do you see the request being made? Is the response what you expect?)? What happens if you add an `error` handler?

Comment: If sucess is not working, try 'error' and check what the error is.

Comment: add an error function to see if the server API is generating an error.

Comment: What is the response? Is it really JSONP? And (I ask this because a lot of people throw Ajax questions at Stackoverflow without understanding this, not because there is any evidence that you don't) do you actually know the difference between JSON and JSONP?

Comment: Chances are the success callback isn't firing due to an error. Add an error key to the passed object. From there you should be able to debug.

Comment: @Quentin the url takes it to my controller where the data is correctly obtained but after that the success function fails to fire up; i have also used the error handler but it dose not go in to it as well. i tried it on FIDDLER - and was able to get the desired data

Comment: What does the response look like?

Comment: no response - nothing even in the Google chrome console window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the contentType and dataType and check the response..
Here an example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:26533/api/Owner',
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function(xhr, type, exception) { 
        // if ajax fails display error alert
        alert("ajax error response type " + type);
    }
});
```

With this you can see what's wrong...